# solving a math question that characters are in a list with python

Tags: python, list, math, calculator, calculation

I have this list `[5, '*', 10, '/', 22]` and I want to write a function that it solve this math thing and return the answer but I have no idea about how I can do it ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` but one should be cautious about it:

```
l=[5, '*', 10, '/', 22]
y=eval(''.join([str(x) for x in l]))
print(y)
```

Comment: but It's answer isn't correct (mathematically)

Comment: @MossBat, it correct. I just checked with the calculator

Comment: @PCM, what answer did you get?

Comment: Well, that is what, the calc shows. Actually, it is technically correct. But probably the division and multiplication got messed up in the `eval`

Answer (score 0):

First, create a string of this expression by using `join` function but make sure all the contents inside the list are of type `<str>`

```
l = [5, '*', 10, '/', 22]
l = [str(x) for x in l]
exp = ''.join(l)
```

Then use `eval` to evaluate the expression string

```
eval(exp)
```

Comment: There's important information you should add concerning the use of `eval`: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score -1):

Or more advanced solution try to use Reverse Polish Notation